# T-SQL - Insert multiple records into Parent and Child Tables

Tags: sql-server

I would like to write a procedure to add multiple parent records with child records in a related table. This is the sort of thing you would do to add multiple Customers in an Customer table and Order items to an CustomerOrder table.

I know the process would be as follows:

1. Insert multiple Customers into Customer table using Insert - Select.
2. Get the primary key of the each Customer record (presuming it’s
   auto-     numbered)
3. Loop: add multiple order records, with the foreign key set to the
   primary key in step 2 above.
4. (Possibly) update the parent invoice parent record with anything
   derived from the child records (such as a total).

I am inserting records into Customer table using Table type parameter and Customer table has auto increment ID, 
How can I pass this auto increment customer ids to Order table?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass this auto increment customer ids to Order table?

You can use `OUTPUT` clause to get the inserted id.

You can refer following sample.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
  ( 
     ID      INT IDENTITY, 
     NAME    VARCHAR(100), 
     ADDRESS VARCHAR(100), 
     PhoneNo VARCHAR(100) 
  ) 

DECLARE @tblInsertdIds TABLE 
  ( 
     ID INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO Customer 
            (Name, 
             Address, 
             PhoneNo) 
OUTPUT      INSERTED.ID 
INTO @tblInsertdIds(ID) 
VALUES      ('C1', 
             'Address 1', 
             '123123123'), 
            ('c2', 
             'Address 2', 
             '34234324') 
--Get the newly inserted ids

SELECT * 
FROM   @tblInsertdIds
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/TSMYY88814)

You can check more details about `OUTPUT` clause at  [**OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Nice solution but I tackled 
`... of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship` Error where two tables are linked. Here in the demo the FK Constraint is missing, so others might hit it as well.